# Find position calibrated camera

Tags: python, c++, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I have a camera that has been calibrated, I have the following data:

```
Camera parameters
    ● Aperture
        ○ height: 4.224 mm
        ○ width: 5.632 mm
    ● Field of View
        ○ horizontal: 39°
        ○ vertical: 29.6°
    ● Camera + Lens distortion:
        ○ k1: -1.2093325853347778
        ○ k2: -1.041786551475525
        ○ k3: 64.01393127441406
        ○ k4: -0.5568028688430786
        ○ k5: -3.6638600826263428
        ○ k6: 78.03067016601562
        ○ p1: -0.004819112829864025
        ○ p2: -0.0027203019708395004
    ● Intrinsic parameters
        ○ cx: 1280
        ○ cy: 960
        ○ fx: 3751.937744140625
        ○ fy: 3821.9775390625
    ● Resolution
        ○ height: 1920
        ○ width: 2560
```

Then, I have a (only one) picture of a chessboard printed in an A4 paper (so I know it's dimensions) that is not perpendicular to the camera.

I know the 4 points of the corners of the chessboard (in pixels).

I want to know the relative position of the camera to the chessboard.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12352602/11261546) question, but they already had the distance to the marker.

- What `OpenCV` functions may I use for this?
- Is it even posible with the information I have?

Comment: use solvePnp which gives you the pose of the object (rotation and translation) with regard to the camera. If you invert that information (e.g. inversion of the 4x4 transformation matrix) you have the camera pose with regard to the object.

Comment: @Micka I thouhgt about it, but how do I get the parameter `objectPoints` ?

Comment: choose a 3D coordinate system to which you want to measure the camera pose, e.g. origin in center of the chessboard. You will need to know the chessboard square size and define objectPoints according to your desired 3D coordinate system, which is quite easy for a chessboard if you know the square size (e.g. in mm)

Comment: @Micka makes sense :) I'll try it

Comment: fx and fy ought to be a lot closer than they are. that's 2% difference. the sensor was manufactured to have square pixels with a lot more precision than that. don't only hold your calibration board parallel to the image plane (directly facing camera). tilt it out of plane. focal length requires observation of "foreshortening". -- k3/k6 have absurd magnitude. likely calibration isn't all that good in the corners of the picture. -- for calibration I'd recommend ChArUco rather than plain old chessboards. charuco gives you more points in the corners of the view, where they're most needed.

Comment: if you print your target, measure it. printers may have slightly different scaling in each direction. -- just show the pattern on your computer screen. it's likely a lot closer to square pixels than what a printer can do, and screens are typically larger than A4. I'd recommend making sure the pattern aligns with the pixel grid (i.e. use squares sizes in a round number of *inches*, because dpi settings are also inches). aliasing would be bad (error of upto half a pixel), and antialiasing is also not ideal.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you, but my question is not about calibrating the camera. that was already done. I will double check the given values according to your comments. I just realize now that the chessboard makes no difference, it could be any A4 sized target

Comment: yeah don't worry, just dumping thoughts here because you might be interested in answers you haven't asked for. and solvepnp was already mentioned.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you mean k3 and k6, are normally ~-1<k<1 as well?

Comment: I can't give exact ranges for these coefficients. I'd expect them to be in the same order of magnitude as the lower order coefficients. lenses, both "flat" and "fishy" ones, typically have most of their distortion in the lower coefficients. the higher ones only "activate" for seriously weird lenses, and for calibrations with few points in the corners, because those coeffs contribute ~0 in the middle of the picture, and numerical optimization can't pin them down without points in the corners of the picture, hence these wild numbers.